# How to get "data" from JQuery Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is the code that I have on index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: "check",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I program test.php to get the "data" that is sent in the AJAX API?

Comment: what do you have in `test.php`? and `data: "check",` it should have to be an object `data: {"keytopass":"check"},`

Comment: In test.php you must return something and you can get return data to your data variable in ajax method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking a very basic question here. You should first go through some Ajax tutorials. Just to help you a little (assuming you are aware of GET and POST methods of sending data), 'data' in data: "check" is different than 'data' in function (data) are different. For clarity, you should name them different as here:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'test.php',
     data: "check",
     success: function(response){
         alert(response);
     }
});
```

This makes it clear that one is data that you are sending to the test.php file in POST parameters and other is the response you are getting from the test.php file after it is run. In fact, the data parameter that you POST to test.php has to be a hash like here (I am assuming the key as "type" here:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'test.php',
     data: {"type":"check"},
     success: function(response){
         alert(response);
     }
});
```

There can obviously be more key-val pairs in data.

So, assuming your test.php file is something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['type'])){
  //Do something
  echo "The type you posted is ".$_POST['type'];
}
```

In this case your alert should read: "The type you posted is check". This will change based on what value you send for 'type' key in AJAX call.

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {"data":"check"},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);//This will alert Success which is sent as the response to the ajax from the server
    }
 });
```

And in test.php

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] == 'check'){
  //$_POST['data'] contain the value that you sent via ajax
  //Do something
  echo 'Success';
}
```

You can  [check this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm) for more

Answer (score 7):

If you want to deals with more datas with jquery ajax. I prefer json data type.

### Simply Use like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"data":"check"},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.value1);
        alert(data.value2);
    }
 });
```

### In your PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] == 'check'){
   //Data 1
     $data['value1'] = 'Data 1 Got Successfully';
    //Data 2
     $data['value2'] = 'Data 2 Got Successfully';
     $resonse = json_encode($data);
     echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML would be

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'test.php',
     data: {"myvar":"check",},
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
     }
     });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that data is an array, so you will have to pass a variable and its value in data. You can pass multiple variables in data, separating them with comma.

And to pick the data sent by your ajax, in test.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['myvar']))
{
  $myVariable = $_POST['myvar'];
  echo $myVariable;   //This would output the string passed in ajax, check
}
?>
```

$_POST is dependent on the type used in the AJAX call. If type is GET, in php it would be $_GET. A simple thing instead would be $_REQUEST, which irrespective of whether the AJAX call is of type GET or POST.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({//create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data:{"data":"check"},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {

           alert(data);
        }
        else {
            alert('Successfully not posted.');
        }
    }
});
```

In test.php

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    echo 'successful';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Output of the PHP file will sent to your AJAX succes function.