# How to receive JSON data from PHP or JSP to Extjs

Tags: php, json, extjs

I've a JSON string, I want to get it in store of Extjs by a PHP url. How to get this string as a JSON from a php file. Something like this:
Extjs file:

[image]

PHP file:

[image]

The result is blank.
What I do now for this work?

Comment: `$temp_data` must be regular php arrays, not JSON strings. At the end, `json_encode` will encode complete array in the right format. Side note: next time copy and paste your code. No screenshots, please.

Comment: In the future, please [use code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/292533) instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

An example of what I believe you mean to do:

```
$array = array();
$test = '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }';
$array[] = json_decode($test);
$test = '{ "firstName":"Jane" , "lastName":"Doe" }';
$array[] = json_decode($test);
$test = '{ "firstName":"Random" , "lastName":"Guy" }';
$array[] = json_decode($test);

print json_encode($array);
exit;
```

Will give you:

```
[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Random","lastName":"Guy"}]
```

As for the Ajax, maybe this will help - [How to get "data" from JQuery Ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700513/how-to-get-data-from-jquery-ajax-requests), or maybe try the Jquery Ajax documentation.