# How to submit a form in one tab and see results in next tab?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

There are three tabs on page. Input,output and review. Html form is in input tab where user enter input in text box. I want to calculate something from that input value and display it in next tab OUTPUT by clicking submit button. 
I already have that file which will do the calculation with that input.

Answers are really appreciated.

```
    <div class="container tabs-wrap">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#input" aria-controls="input" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Input</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#output" aria-controls="output" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Output</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#review" aria-controls="review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Review &amp; Email</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="input">
  <h2>Web based two tier ground mount bill of material generator</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="output.php" method="post" target="_blank">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="count">Module Count:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="count" placeholder="Enter Number of Modules" name="count">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary continue">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: post with working example in the snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: also, have you tried something out? if yes, then it could be helpful to include in the question so others could either extend on your solution or suggest something else

Comment: [link](http://hespv.ca/material/tabs.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
    // your code goes here
    $('#outputSpan').text($('#count').val());
    // not triiger output tab to be open
    $('[href="#output"]').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container tabs-wrap">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#input" aria-controls="input" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Input</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#output" aria-controls="output" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Output</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#review" aria-controls="review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Review &amp; Email</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="input">
      <h2>Web based two tier ground mount bill of material generator</h2>
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="output.php" method="post" target="_blank">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="count">Module Count:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="count" placeholder="Enter Number of Modules" name="count">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary continue">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="output">
      <h2>Output</h2>
      <span id="outputSpan"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, You got what i was trying to explain. Ok so right now the output tab is displaying the number we enter in input tab. What i want is get the number from input tab and then do some calculation with it then display result in output tab.

Comment: @veenu No one can understand your **Do some calculation with it**, I have given solution and a way how you can make your requirement. So  do calculation with the input field value and display it in the output element.

Comment: Sorry, rohan for making this ambigous, i am new with javascript and php. What i was trying to do is get that number and lets say add 15 to it, display in output tab.

Comment: You can try it like `$('#outputSpan').text(parseInt($('#count').val())+15);`

Comment: That works, but that calculation was just for example. In realty i want to do bunch of calculations just with that value. So i made a different file for that 
which is like <?php $mod_width = $module_count/2; and some more like this. So how can i display the result of this file in that tab.

Comment: You must have to use AJAX for this Read [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700513/how-to-get-data-from-jquery-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you should have all three tabs in one html file (not separate files). Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for more info.

You could attach a function to the "continue" button that handles the calculation

```
$(".continue").on("click", function () {
      //Handle calculation, changing tabs and writing results here
      // do your calculations here
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#output"]').tab('show'); // change active tab
      $( '.resultElemClass' ).text('calculationValue'); // output the result
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i see what you are suggesting. All the tabs are already in one html file. I like your idea of attaching function in javascript but wanna ask what is this .resultElemClass.?  What i want is get the number from input tab and then do some calculation with it then display result in output tab. For the calculation i have a php file or i can include that file in this file also.

Comment: hi @veenu - the .resultElemClass is just an example element you can inject your result into. For example, you create a span with the class of "resultElemClass" and then use jQuery to inject result there (depending on how you want to output the results. Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this:

```
onFormSubmit(calculatedValue){
  $('#output').html(calculatedValue);
}
```

The logic is that when you successfully submit a form, make sure that you append the calculated value to the #output, or which ever div you want to append it to.

If you are using AJAX to communicate with PHP, it would look something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "file.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function (response) {
           // you will get calculated value from your php page (what you echo or print) 
          $('#output').html(response);                       
        }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output tab is another view file, you can use export function of javascript. Like take the input process it as per your needs and then use function like:

```
// file1.js
export function value() {
  return "Your output";
}
```

file1 is where you will be accepting input or processing the input

```
// output.js
import {hello} from 'file1'; // or './file1'
let val = value(); // val is Your output;
```

Make sure to put an 'if' in your output file and refresh it after a certain time interval(1 sec or so) so get the value as soon as it is available.

Comment: NO output tab is not another view file. All the tabs are in one html file.What i want is get the number from input tab and then do some calculation with it then display result in output tab. For the calculation i have a php file or i can include that file in this file also.